# Nodejs, moch/chai failing with "Segmentation fault: 11" on macOS

Tags: node.js, macos, mocha.js, chai

I am running mocha/chai (3.2.0/3.5.0) based test cases for my nodejs (6.10.2) based application, on macOS 10.12.4, and I am running into a "Segmentation fault: 11" failure.

So far I have tried:

- Erasing my node_modules folder and doing a new `npm install`
- Checking for outdated dependencies and upgrading them
- Upgrading the nodejs version (was using 6.7.0), via `sudo port upgrade nodejs6`

The code that is failing for me is as follows.

```
    chai.request(url)
        .post(`/api/filestore?token=${token}`)
        .timeout(20000)
        .attach('file', fs.readFileSync(filepath), filename)
        .field('name', data.name)
        .field('description', data.description)
        .field('keywords', data.keywords)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) { done(err); }
            res.should.have.status(200);
            res.should.be.json;
            res.body.should.have.property('name');
            res.body.should.have.property('description');
            res.body.should.have.property('categories');
            res.body.keywords.should.be.a('array');
            res.body.keywords.join(',').should.be.equal(data.keywords);
            done();
        });
```

The segmentation fault disappears when I remove the 'attach' line:

```
.attach('file', fs.readFileSync(filepath), filename)
```

I have tried the `fs.readFileSync(filepath)` separately and I don't encounter the issue.

This wasn't an issue in the past and only became an issue recently. I am wondering whether it coincides with the upgrade of the OS, but I can't be sure. Test file is only 34K in size.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: Failing on Ubuntu test machine as well with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Weird... maybe a read permission issue? If you do the `fs.readFileSync()` bit _before_ the test, then pass the file object to the `attach()` method do you get the same? This would tell you if it was the readFile or the attach that segfaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the chai code was a 'red herring'. Using the [segfault-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/segfault-handler) node module, I was able to establish that the issue was actually being caused by code in the project being tested (it is running in the same process).

In my case, the stack trace suggested the issue was being caused by something in the sqlite3 code. Further investigation revealed it was due to not handling the return value of in the function passed to `Promise.mapSeries`, which was doing a sqlite SQL operation, via Sequelize.

Note I am using bluebird for my promises.

Comment: Try installing Node using [the official installer](https://nodejs.org/en/) (and afterwards, rebuild all dependencies to make sure they are linked against that new version).

Comment: It was a consistent failure on both VM generated for continuous builds, using Ubuntu, and my local machine,  which uses macOS.